# Can't get Worldwide Web Publishing Service working in Windows 10

Tags: iis, webserver, windows-10, dcom, component-services

I had to reinstall Windows today to solve some other problems with corrupted drivers.  Everything was going well until I tried to start IIS, but the Worldwide Web Publishing Service wasn't running.  I tried to start it and received a message that it couldn't be started.  Checking the Event Log, I found the following entry:

> The World Wide Web Publishing Service service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
>   The dependency service or group failed to start.

I checked to make sure the Distributed Transaction Coordinator, RPC Endpoint Mapper, and Windows Process Activation Service are all running, so I don't know what the problem is.  I've uninstalled IIS, rebooted, reinstalled, rebooted again, and still have the same issue.

***EDIT***
I tried the steps shown in the answer below, but they didn't work.  I can't change any of the settings on the class in DCOM Config under Component Services.  Looking in the System log, this is what I see now:

> After trying the fixes shown, this is what I'm still getting: "The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID {8D8F4F83-3594-4F07-8369-FC3C3CAE4919} and APPID {F72671A9-012C-4725-9D2F-2A4D32D65169} to the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool."

Can anyone offer insight into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and found a fix here: http://www.windowscentral.com/heres-whats-been-fixed-and-whats-broken-windows-10-insider-build-14942

To quote from that page:

> Run the following from an admin cmd line (or edit the registry accordingly): REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC /v
>   SvcHostSplitDisable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
>
> REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WAS /v
>   SvcHostSplitDisable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
>
> Reboot the system, so that the W3Svc and WAS services share a service
>   host process.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try checking all the logs, System, Application, Security? Maybe there's a permission error or something else that turns up elsewhere.

Also did you install the IIS Management Console?

Just to debug, you could install the entire tree under Internet Information Services and see if that works. If so, then slowly remove things one by one until it fails again.

Here's a solution from a forum on the other error you saw http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/event-id-10016-the-application-specific-permission/9ff8796f-c352-4da2-9322-5fdf8a11c81e
:

1. Open Regedit.
2. Go to HKEY_Classes_Root\CLSID*CLSID*.
   Note: *CLSID* stand for the ID that appears in your event viewer error. In your case, it's {C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}.
3. Right click on it then select permission.
4. Click Advance and change the owner to administrator. Also click the box that will appear below the owner line.
5. Apply full control.
6. Close the tab then go to HKEY_LocalMachine\Software\Classes\AppID*APPID*.
   Note: *AppID* is the ID that appears in your event viewer. In your case it's {316CDED5-E4AE-4B15-9113-7055D84DCC97}.
7. Right click on it then select permission.
8. Click Advance and change the owner to administrators.
9. Click the box that will appear below the owner line.
10. Click Apply and grant full control to Administrators.
11. Close all tabs and go to Administrative tool.
12. Open component services.
13. Click Computer, click my computer, then click DCOM.
14. Look for the corresponding service that appears on the error viewer.
15. Right click on it then click properties.
16. Click security tab then click Add User. Add SYSTEM then apply.
17. Tick the Activate local box.

So use the relevant keys here and the DCOM Config should give you access to the greyed out areas:

CLSID:

{D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}

and APPID

{9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}

Comment: Here's a message in the System log: "The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}
 and APPID 
{9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool." How do I fix this?

Comment: The problem is that ***most*** of this answer does go as shown.  However, when I open the DCOM Config, it doesn't show either of the two CLSIDs in the event viewer.  Now what?

Comment: Dumb question, but you're using the CLSID and APPID on your system and not the ones pasted from the forum answer?

Comment: I'm using the ones from the Event Viewer

Comment: I found one of the CLSIDs, but when I choose its properties under DCOM Config, none of the options can be changed.  Any thoughts on this?